# How to get a Maven reactor build order (artifactId) in a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project for which I would like to get the list of artifactId in the order the maven reactor will arrange them. Can this be done with a maven command line ?

So far I have had partial information with

```
mvn validate
```

but this is print the project name and what I want is the artifactId.

Comment: First why do you need that? What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to do that:

```
mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.artifactId}' org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get a list of artifacts regarding parallel builds? (mvn -T 4 ...)
I would like to use it to send build commands to Jenkins.